# Merging two lists and printing the new one out via recursion

Tags: java, list, recursion

So, I have the 2 lists (main part of the task, cant change anything here codewise)

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    List<Integer> as = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 7; i >= 1; i -= 2) as.add(i);
    List<Integer> bs = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 2; i <= 6; i -= 2) bs.add(i);
    System.out.println(serialize(zip(as, bs), " + "));
}
```

Serialize looks like this

```
public static String serialize(List<Integer> vs, String sep){
    if (vs.isEmpty()) return "";
    if (vs.size() == 1) return vs.get(0) + "";
    return vs.remove(0) + sep + serialize(vs, sep);
}
```

and returns a String of numbers seperated by "+".
Now I build this

```
    public static List<Integer> zip(List<Integer> vs, List<Integer> ws){
    List<Integer> cs = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    return  zip(vs, ws, cs);

}

public static List<Integer> zip(List<Integer> vs, List<Integer> ws, List<Integer> cs){
    ListIterator<Integer> e = vs.listIterator();
    if (e.hasNext()) {
        cs.add(e.next());
        vs.remove(0);
        zip(ws, vs, cs);
    }
    return cs; 
}
```

Which creates a list cs and fills it in zip(vs, ws, cs) with the first item from vs, removes the item v(0) and does it again but switches vs with ws. (If that makes sense). 
Now my problem is this causes an infinite loop because it doesnt terminate.

Where did my brain fail me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line causes the infinite loop:

```
 for (int i = 2; i <= 6; i -= 2) bs.add(i);
```

Not that you decrement `i` and the condition is that it's `<= 6`.

Comment: Ohgod, thank you so much. So hard to see small mistakes like that after only 2 months of java.:)